# Django template: condition check with previous object

Tags: django, django-templates

I need check the condition with previous object in loop.

(previous_object) is for illustration only.

```
{% for object in objects %}

{% if (previous_object).clicks == 0 %} #this reference must be based on the loop's previous object.

<button type="submit"> OK </button>

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in using `{% ifchanged %}` filter. This condition is true only when a feature of an item is different from previous item in the list.

```py
{% for item in items %}
    {% ifchanged item.clicks %}
        <button type="submit"> OK </button>
    {% endifchanged %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This would be nice if ```clicks``` were a booleanfield. But ```click``` is an integerfield, so all objects have different ```clicks``` field than the previous ones.